# Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?

Tags: support, original-proofs

Is providing link to my (8 pages) proof of P=NP and asking to check my proof appropriate for a CS Theory question?

The proof is on professional mathematician level (uses advanced logics) and does not produce a crackpot impression (except that it is short, 8 pages).

Comment: [math.meta.se]: [Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35920) and meta.mathoverflow: [Is asking to verify my P=NP proof appropriate?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5743/). The answer was no in both of those places...

Comment: And the closest answer I can find on this site is here https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/281/3431 but substitute "paper on the arXiv" with "my paper"

Comment: And see also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f/18570#18570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  This is not appropriate here, or likely on any Stack Exchange Site.  See, e.g., [About "Are there any known barriers to use some approach for solving P vs. NP?"](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1026/5038) and [Is it ok to ask about the correctness of preprints on crank-friendly topics?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/274/5038).

A claim to have a solution for a well-known, difficult open problem is [an extraordinary claim requiring extraordinary evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#.22Extraordinary_claims.22). A request for us to check such an alleged proof would not be a good post for SE; it is not our goal here to make broad advances to science in a single post. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-to-deal-with-questions-about-crank-heavy-topics) for a related discussion.

Moreover, requests for us to check a paper-length work for correctness are not suitable here.  That's too much to expect from a single question here.